# What does the data field mean in an Elrond transaction?

Tags: base64, blockchain, decode, multiversx

If I call the transaction endpoint from the API gateway:

https://testnet-gateway.elrond.com/transaction/89a15e2ea521764d21ac2de83064dd7c1848f83dff4dcbad0518fdf41a70d889

I get the following data:

> "data":"RVNEVE5GVFRyYW5zZmVyQDRkNDU1ODQ2NDE1MjRkMmQ2MjM5MzM2NTM2MzBAMDEyMzRmQDA1OWUxZDQ2YTljM2I4OWNhMkAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDUwMDRmNzllYzQ0YmIxMzM3MmI1YWM5ZDk5NmQ3NDkxMjBmNDc2NDI3NjI3Y2ViQDYzNmY2ZDcwNmY3NTZlNjQ1MjY1Nzc2MTcyNjQ3Mw=="

What does it represent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That "**data**" field is encoded in **base64** and it represents the **Input Data** field available in explorer:

https://testnet-explorer.elrond.com/transactions/89a15e2ea521764d21ac2de83064dd7c1848f83dff4dcbad0518fdf41a70d889

> ESDTNFTTransfer@4d45584641524d2d623933653630@01234f@059e1d46a9c3b89ca2@000000000000000005004f79ec44bb13372b5ac9d996d749120f476427627ceb@636f6d706f756e6452657761726473

It can be decoded using [an online base64 decoder](https://www.base64decode.org/).